# Find first and last value of a Group By - Postgres - Crypto Candlesticks

Tags: sql, postgresql, cryptography, bitcoin

I have a table with 1m candlesticks for BTC/USDT and using that data, I would like to quickly generate 1h candlesticks. I am currently stuck on how to retrieve the first value from a GROUP BY of 60 rows (=>60min per hour).

It would look something like this

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(open)
FROM table  GROUP BY CEILING(unix_timestamp/(60*60));
```

where open is the open value for each candlestick.

Unix_timestamp is used to store the timestamp of every row / candlestick. Hence you group by all timestamps that fall into the same hour.

How do I retrieve a certain value from the first and last row of the group by statement?

These are the columns:

```
id-unix-open-high-low-close-volume
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide some sample data and the expected results? Preferably in a fiddle :)

Comment: Thank you, how do I add a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on`.  If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (CEILING(unix_timestamp/(60*60))) t.*
FROM table t
ORDER BY CEILING(unix_timestamp/(60*60), unix_timestamp;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work.

I need to group the candlesticks from 1 minute candlesticks to 1 hour candlesticks. Out of that group, I need to select the first 'open' value, the one with the smallest unix timestamp.

Comment: @digitalnomad21 . . . I don't know what the first "open" value is.  But this should be returning the first row for each hour.